# Need help creating query using the data below

Tags: sql-server, case

if PaytypeID=111 then indicate the transaction is paid by coupon(ignore other PayTypes); all other cases indicate - no coupon

```
SELECT      *
FROM        Payment  

TransID SalesDate   Amount PayTypeID
222222  2014-08-29  10.00  111
222222  2014-08-29  15.00  222
222222  2014-08-29  15.00  333
555555  2014-09-29  10.00  100
555555  2014-09-29  10.00  101
666666  2014-09-29  10.00  105
666666  2014-09-29  10.00  106
777777  2014-10-29  10.00  107
```

Want output as follows..

```
TransID SalesDate   Amount CouponUsed
222222  2014-08-29  40.00  1
555555  2014-09-29  20.00  0
666666  2014-09-29  20.00  0
777777  2014-10-29  10.00  0
```

Comment: Check out the CASE statement.

Comment: I tried `Case` but I want the result grouped by `TransID'

Comment: Would you please specify what `CouponUsed` is?

Comment: Say when we go shopping, we pay with cash, debit card, visa, amex, coupon/gift cert and many other ways... so 111 is the coupon/gift card and we are only interested to know which transactions had gift coupons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your select statement

```
case when PayTypeID=111 then 1 else 0 end CouponUsed
```

Edit: if you want to summarise and group it by TransID:

```
Select TransID, SalesDate, sum(Amount), max(case when PayTypeID=111 then 1 else 0 end) CouponUsed
from Payment
group by TransID, SalesDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly which columns you want but you can use a *, .... like so

```
    Select * , case when PayTypeID = 111 then 'Coupon Used' else 'no coupon' end as CouponUsed
    from Payment
```

You can tweak it a bit from there but the case when is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, the result need to be grouped/shown at TransID level.